# Is there a way of appending a point to a line with RethinkDB

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

Assuming I am creating a geospatial line object with the same syntax as described in the documentation

```
r.table('geo').insert({
    id: 101,
    route: r.line([-122.423246,37.779388], [-121.886420,37.329898])
}).run(conn, callback);
```

Is there a way of appending a point to this line without using an atomic (read/write) pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already inserted the document into the database and want to add a point to that document, you can use the `udpate` command with the `toGeojson` command in order to do that.

Here's how that would look:

```
r.table('30711279').get(101)
  .update(function (row)  {
    return {
      'route': r.line(r.args(
        row('route').toGeojson()('coordinates')
            .append([ -120, 85 ])
      ))
    }
  }, {nonAtomic: true })
```

Basically, I'm creating a new line in the `route` property. I'm passing it all the old points as an array and then appending a new tuple with the longitude and latitude.

If you still haven't inserted the document into the database and wanted to add a point to that line, you could just do this:

```
var arrayOfPoints = [[-122.423246,37.779388], [-121.886420,37.329898]];
var point = [ -120, 57 ];

r.table('geo').insert({
    id: 101,
    route: r.line(r.args(arrayOfPoints.concat(point)))
}).run(conn, callback);
```

Comment: Thanks, the update method is what I was looking for, guess i cant avoid loading the entire route into memory before appending though

Comment: No, you can't. But keep in mind that this is all happening in the database, not in your application. That's much faster than doing it in your application logic.